# C++ error: no match for 'operator<<' in '"Data for " << Rover::getName()()'

Tags: c++, class

I'm working on a bit of code for my C++ class, and I'm a bit stuck.

Here's the bit of the assignment I'm working on:

---

Within the Rover class, specify the following member instance variables:

```
 name (String)

 x position on a grid (integer)

 y position on a grid (integer)

 direction by compass – N, S, E, or W (String)

 speed (0 – 5 meters per second, integer)
```

Within the Rover class, specify the following methods:

```
 No-arg constructor – set the rover’s position to (0,0), its speed to 0, 
  its direction to North,and its name to Default

 Constructor that receives parameters to initialize all five 
  instance variables described above

 Setter methods for each instance variable

 Getter methods for each instance variable

 getRoverData – returns a string that displays values for each instance 
  variable of the current rover object, placing each value on a separate line, 
  as follows:
```

So right now I just want to get the base case to work. Here's the entirety of my code:

---

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Rover.h"

using namespace std;


int main() {

    Rover rover1;

    rover1.setDefaultValues();

    cout<<rover1.getRoverData(rover1)<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

rover.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Rover.h"
using namespace std;

//put functions in here

void Rover::setDefaultValues() {
    name = "Default";
    xcoord = 0;
    ycoord = 0;
    direction = "N";
    speed = 0;

}

void Rover::constructRover() {

}

void Rover::setXcoord(int xcoord) {
    this->xcoord = xcoord;
}

void Rover::setYcoord(int ycoord) {
    this->ycoord = ycoord;

}

void Rover::setName(string name) {
    this->name = name;
}

void Rover::setDirection(string direction) {
    this->direction = direction;
}

void Rover::setSpeed(int speed) {
    this->speed = speed;
}

int Rover::getXcoord() {
    return xcoord;

}

int Rover::getYcoord() {
    return ycoord;
}

string Rover::getName() {
    return name;
}

string Rover::getDirection() {
    return direction;
}

int Rover::getSpeed() {
    return speed;
}

string Rover::getRoverData(Rover rover) {
    string printStatement = "";
    printStatement.append("Data for " << rover.getName());
    printStatement.append("\nX: " << Rover::xcoord);
    printStatement.append("\nY: " << Rover::ycoord);
    printStatement.append("\nDirection: " << Rover::direction);
    printStatement.append("\nSpeed: " << Rover::speed);
    return printStatement;

}
```

Rover.h:

```
/* 
 * File:   Rover.h
 * Author: Matthew
 *
 * Created on May 14, 2012, 8:10 PM
 */


#ifndef ROVER_H
#define ROVER_H

using namespace std;


class Rover
{
        private:
            string name;
            int xcoord;
            int ycoord;
            string direction;
            int speed;


    public:
            void setDefaultValues();
            void constructRover();
            //XCoordinates
            void setXcoord(int xcoord);
            int getXcoord();
            //YCoordinates
            void setYcoord(int ycoord);
            int getYcoord();
            //Name
            void setName(string name);
            string getName();
            //Direction
            void setDirection(string direction);
            string getDirection();
            //Speed
            void setSpeed(int speed);
            int getSpeed();
            //Printout
            string getRoverData(Rover rover);

};

#endif  /* ROVER_H */
```

The error I'm currently getting is:

```
rover.cpp:64: error: no match for 'operator<<' in '"Data for " << Rover::getName()()'
```

*The heck does that mean?*

At this point, what I want the printout to say is:

```
Data for Default
X: 0
Y: 0
Direction: N
Speed: 0
```

Any thoughts?

Sorry if the code looks awful as I posted it...haven't done this before.

---

**UPDATE:**

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Rover.h"
using namespace std;

//put functions in here

void Rover::setDefaultValues() {
    name = "Default";
    xcoord = 0;
    ycoord = 0;
    direction = "N";
    speed = 0;

}

void Rover::constructRover() {

}

void Rover::setXcoord(int xcoord) {
    this->xcoord = xcoord;
}

void Rover::setYcoord(int ycoord) {
    this->ycoord = ycoord;

}

void Rover::setName(string name) {
    this->name = name;
}

void Rover::setDirection(string direction) {
    this->direction = direction;
}

void Rover::setSpeed(int speed) {
    this->speed = speed;
}

int Rover::getXcoord() {
    return xcoord;

}

int Rover::getYcoord() {
    return ycoord;
}

string Rover::getName() {
    return name;
}

string Rover::getDirection() {
    return direction;
}

int Rover::getSpeed() {
    return speed;
}

string Rover::getRoverData(Rover rover) {
    string printStatement = "";
    printStatement.append("Data for " + rover.getName());
    printStatement.append("\nX: " + rover.getXcoord());
    printStatement.append("\nY: " + rover.getYcoord());
    printStatement.append("\nDirection: " + rover.getDirection());
    printStatement.append("\nSpeed: " + rover.getSpeed());
    return printStatement;

}
```

So, now the printout is:

```
Data for Default
X:
Y:
Direction: N
Speed:
```

So, it basically just won't print out the zeroes. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<<` is the stream insertion operator. There is no function anywhere that takes a `const char[]` left hand side and a `std::string` right hand side. Therefore, you're getting errors.

You may use this combination when using `cout`, but it's a bit deceptive. A call of:

```
std::cout << "Some string" << someStdString;
```

Is defined as:

```
(std::cout << "Some string") <<  someStdString;
```

The actual call is equivalent to:

```
operator<< (operator<< (std::cout, "Some string"), someStdString);
```

The thing that makes it work is that the inside call returns the same `cout` is was passed in so that it can be used with the other call. If you don't use something like `cout` that exhibits this behaviour, it won't work the same way. This is also why you can say:

```
int i = 5 + 2 + 3;
```

The 5 + 2 returns an `int`, which is added with 3, and that returns the `int` assigned to `i`.

To concatenate the string inside, you can just replace that with a plus, since addition for strings and char arrays is defined as part of std::string, or add another `append` call:

```
printStatement.append("Data for " + rover.getName());
//or
printStatement.append("Data for ");
printStatement.append(rover.getName());
//or
printStatement += "Data for " + rover.getName();
```

**Update:**

To answer your other inquiry, this is another feature of C++ that isn't part of Java. I didn't realize you were adding ints onto some of them. When you do that, the character array in the quotes actually decays into a pointer. Then, pointer arithmetic is used to add the integer. Not what you wanted at all. So basically you're passing in the pointer to the beginning of the string literal, moved forward x characters, where x is the number you're adding to it. Adding 0 means it just stays there, so the whole string is passed and the `+ 0` is pretty much dead code.

If you're going to be adding ints on, you need a way to convert the integers to strings, and then add them on. C++11 has `stoi`, but that's the opposite of what you want. Instead, you can use a stringstream, among other methods:

```
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << 5; //the int to be converted
    std::string s = ss.str(); //get the string
    cout << s + " is the number"; //print with an added string
}
```

Comment: Yes! It compiles! Thank you so much! It's doing something weird now though, see next post

Comment: I updated my answer with more theory if you want to take a look.

Comment: Ohhh, very nice. That's super helpful :) Can't tell I'm a Java guy can you? ;) Even though I don't like Java at all and greatly prefer C++!

Comment: Yes, I was surprised when I found out Java doesn't have operator overloading. It can be abused pretty badly, but for most uses it's very helpful. Imagine making a `BigInt` class and not being able to use `a + b`.

Comment: Sorry, getting used to the forum rules, I placed the new question in an update to the main question :) Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Oh man, you're awesome. That's EXACTLY what I needed. Let me buy you an internet beer....(buys beer)  Cheers! Thank you!!!